# Calculation of PSD using Hamming Window

Tags: matlab

I have 600000 time domain Data. I want to calculate the psd using that data. But I want to use hamming window to my data set and overlapping them to get a smooth psd vs. frequency graph. I need a matlab code to conduct this.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Why Hamming window?

Comment: I have taken the full data and calculate the fft of that data and then finally calculate the psd of that data. I want to use hamming window to segmented my whole data into 10 equal parts and compute the psd of each part and then overlap them to get the psd.

Comment: see https://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/pwelch.html

Comment: you should be careful,  the term “psd” isn’t the same as DFT although a lot of people use it that way.